# Exporting table data into csv format from server to local

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have connected to remote server and trying to export a table data to local using the command:

```
copy finance.coa to 'localusername@172.16.1.44:/home/kedarisettyakhiles/akki.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

I am getting the error:

> relative path not allowed for COPY to file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
  psql postgres://username:password@ip:port/database_name -c "\copy table_name TO 
 'table.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
```

Remove `password` if not needed `postgres://username@ip:port/database_name`.

Comment: I am using this from my local :-                                                                               psql postgres://postgres@172.16.0.70:5432/enet -c "\copy finance.coa to 'tabl.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"                                                                                        
                                                                                                                            
 This time i am getting a different error:-                                                                  
tabl.csv: Permission denied

Comment: `psql enet -c "\copy finance.coa TO 
 'table.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"` @akhileshkedarisetty

Comment: After trying that i am getting :-                                                                                 psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist

Comment: When i am using this syntax :-                                                                                        psql -h 172.16.0.70 -U postgres -d enet -o export.csv -c 'select * from finance.coa';    
 the file is storing in the local. But the problem is that, It's not storing in the proper csv format.

Comment: @akhileshkedarisetty you can modify the csv format in the copy clause https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-copy.html

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems:

- `COPY` writes to a file *on the database server*.

  If you want to write to a file on the client machine, use `psql`'s `\copy` which runs `COPY ... TO STDOUT` under the hood.
- You cannot specify a host and user name in the file name in the hope that the file will be transferred to another machine. It has to be a path on the file system (for `COPY`, it has to be an absolute path on the server's file system, hence the error message).

Start `psql` on the machine where you want the file to end up and use `\copy`:

```
\copy finance.coa to '/home/kedarisettyakhiles/akki.csv' (FORMAT 'csv', DELIMITER ',', HEADER)
```

Comment: It's showing:-       drwxr-xr-x 24 kedarisettyakhiles kedarisettyakhiles 4096 Aug 27 16:00 /home/kedarisettyakhiles/

Comment: Looks ok. Not sure where you are going wrong. Use `strace` to debug this.

Comment: Whats strace? How to use it?

Comment: This leads too far - ask your system administrator for help. She can probably help you figure out what went wrong.

Comment: As, I came to know that /tmp location doesn't contain any privileges, I tried giving the path  /tmp location. So the file was stored with complete data using copy.